# Understanding equals method

Tags: java, equals

J. Bloch in his effective Java provides a several rules for the implementation for equals method. Here they are:

> • Reflexive: For any non-null reference value x, x.equals(x) must
> return true.
>
> • Symmetric: For any non-null reference values x and y,
> x.equals(y) must return true if and only if y.equals(x) returns true.
>
> • Transitive: For any non-null reference values x, y, z, if
> x.equals(y) returns true and y.equals(z) returns true, then
> x.equals(z) must return true.
>
> • Consistent: For any non-null reference
> values x and y, multiple invocations of x.equals(y) consistently
> return true or consistently return false, provided no information used
> in equals comparisons on the objects is modified.
>
> • For any non-null
> reference value x, x.equals(null) must return false.

But later in the book he mentioned so-called Liskov substitution principle:

> The Liskov substitution principle says that any important property of
> a type should also hold for its subtypes, so that any method written
> for the type should work equally well on its subtypes

I don't see how it ties to the `equals` contracts. Should we actually adhere to it while writing the equals implementation?

The question is about implementing the method for subclasses.  Here is the example from the book:

```
private static final Set<Point> unitCircle;

static {
    unitCircle = new HashSet<Point>();
    unitCircle.add(new Point(1, 0));
    unitCircle.add(new Point(0, 1));
    unitCircle.add(new Point(-1, 0));
    unitCircle.add(new Point(0, -1));
}

public static boolean onUnitCircle(Point p) {
    return unitCircle.contains(p);
}

public class CounterPoint extends Point {
    private static final AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();

    public CounterPoint(int x, int y) {
        super(x, y);
        counter.incrementAndGet();
    }

    public int numberCreated() { return counter.get(); }
}
```

and the following implementation:

```
// Broken - violates Liskov substitution principle (page 40)
@Override public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (o == null || o.getClass() != getClass())
        return false;
    Point p = (Point) o;
    return p.x == x && p.y == y;
}
```

Ok, violates and what then? I don't understand.

Comment: also superclasses shouldn't know his childs but object knows string class^^ java is not well designed at all.

Comment: @Zelldon Please elaborate, what do you mean by "object knows string"? (I am not following your claim)

Comment: Object has `toString()` method.

Comment: It also has getClass() method :|

Comment: I actually don't understand the need of "but" in your question. Where is the contradiction?

Comment: @MarounMaroun He provided the implementation of the equals method used reflection (Class objects comparison) and said that the implemenation violated the principle. Moreover he said __There is no way to extend an instantiable class and add a value component while preserving the equals contract__

Comment: @MarounMaroun I've added some to the question.

Comment: Here is a [discussion](https://www.artima.com/intv/bloch17.html) that shows the dilemma.

Comment: You can follow this principal until the day you revert it back, and this happens overtime.

Comment: The numberCreated-method is non-static (the counter field is static)? But not relevant for the equals method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are typically 2 ways how to check the type in the equals method:

**Option 1: instanceof**

```
if (! (obj instanceof ThisClass)){
    return false;
}
```

This option **respects** the *Liskov substitution principle*. But you **cannot** add additional properties in sub classes which are relevant for the equals method without breaking the characteristics of an equivalence relation (reflexive, symmetric, transitive).

**Option 2: getClass()**

```
if (obj == null || ! this.getClass().equals(obj.getClass())) {
    return false;
}
```

This option **violates** the *Liskov substitution principle*. But you **can** add additional properties in sub classes which are relevant for the equals method without breaking the characteristics of an equivalence relation (reflexive, symmetric, transitive).

Joshua Bloch warns about this in his book "Effective Java".

Angelika Langer however mentions a way for "mixed-tpye" comparisons, if you can define default values for additional properties:

http://www.angelikalanger.com/Articles/JavaSolutions/SecretsOfEquals/Equals-2.html

The downside is that the equals methods becomes rather complicated.

> ```
> // Broken - violates Liskov substitution principle (page 40)
> @Override public boolean equals(Object o) {
>     if (o == null || o.getClass() != getClass())
>         return false;
>     Point p = (Point) o;
>     return p.x == x && p.y == y;
> }
> ```
>
> Ok, violates and what then? I don't understand.

So if you have a sub class such as MyPoint (which might add additional methods but not additional properties/ fields), then

```
Point p1 = new Point(x, y);
Point p2 = new MyPoint(x, y);

p1.equals(p2) == false

Set<Point> points = new HashSet<>();
points.add(p1);

points.contains(p2) == false;
```

although both objects really represent the same point.

If you would use option 1 (instanceof) instead, the equals method would return true.

Comment: The thing is J.B. suggest not using inheritance ever. He proposed to use composition instead for such cases. That's clear concept, yes. I was wondered by the fact the he said we cannot implement equals in a correct way for subclasses ever.

Comment: The subclasses of abstract classes of course are not considered.

Comment: I don't see, in option 1, why you cannot add new attributes in sub classes. I mean, for the super class equals you won't check the subclasses attributes only its own attributes, the sub classes should check their own attributes. If you are comparing an object with an instance of a subclass then only the higher class attributes are relevant.

Comment: @St.Antario I don't have the book at hand right now, but I'm pretty sure this is only true for subclasses which have additional fields/ properties which are relevant for the equals method (so you would have to override the equals method -> breaks the equivalence relation).

Comment: @prmottajr Becuase it's not going to be possible to implement equals for the sublclass in a correct way. If you know how to do that, please post it, I would look at the example.

Comment: @prmottajr This would break transitivity: ColorPoint p1: x, y, red ; Point p2: x, y ; ColorPoint p3: x, y, green. Your algorithm: p1 == p2 && p2 == p3. Transitivity requires in this case p1 == p3, but p1 != p3 -> broken!

Comment: So, in a few words, we shouldn't override equals from non-abstract classes which override equals, correct?

Comment: @St.Antario Well many people work with option 2 and live with the consequences. But generally, yes, I recommend to use option 1 and not to override the equals method except the one from Object. You could declare it final to make sure it doesn't get overridden somewhere.

Comment: @puce p1 does not have to be equal to p3 if you are comparing then as ColorPoint but if you are using Point references then they should be equal. Although in Java the overloaded method would be used, and then it would compare the extra attributes. I see your point.

Comment: This is really making confuse to me. Can you clarify which Option is good at which situation?

Comment: @Anil There is no strict rule. I suggest to use option 1 + composition. If you have a situation where you need to override the equals method of a subclass, consider option 2. Often it doesn't really matter e.g in closed source projects where you are sure there is no subclass/ know how the classes are used (though if this might change in the future - this can create strange, hard to find bugs). Some IDEs generate option 2, if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I think he is trying to say that the characteristic of a point is its coordinates. So you would expect this to be true:

```
new Point(0, 0).equals(new CounterPoint(0, 0));
```

because the two points have the same coordinates, even if they don't have the same type. But the proposed equals method will return false because the two objects have different classes.

If you think of collections for example, this is true:

```
new LinkedList().equals(new ArrayList());
```

The two lists don't have the same type but they have the same content (in this case they are both empty) and are therefore considered equal.

Comment: So, the implementation doesn't actually violates equalses contract but I agree, seems counterintuitive. Is that the reason he suggest we don't write quals in such a way?